# Elasticsearch 5.0 JAVA API 5.0 on JDK 7

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

My system is compiled on **JDK 1.7** and I need to use the **Elasticsearch 5.0**. I want to use the **Elasticsearch JAVA API 5.0** on this system and I cannot change the JDK version that my system is compiled though. How can I proceed since that API is compiled on JAVA 1.8 and I got the ***Unsupported major.minor version 52.0*** error?

Answer (score 0):

> The low level REST client is 1.7 compatible. But it does not provide
>   all builders you have in the older transport client. You have to
>   upgrade to 1.8 or stay with elasticsearch 2.x

dadoonetDavid PilatoDeveloper | Evangelist
https://discuss.elastic.co/users/dadoonet